# nodejs's lazy.lines.forEach not forEaching over aws cli tool output

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, lazy-evaluation

if anyone out there is trying to use amazon's AWS api with nodejs like me can you please enlighten as to why...

```
child = exec("ssh root\@<server> \"/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-instances --output table|grep AvailabilityZone|sed 's/ //g'|sed 's/||||//g'|cut -d'|' -f2\"", function(err,zoneout) {
        console.log(zoneout);
        new lazy(zoneout).lines.forEach(function(aline){
              console.log("so lazy");
              //if(zones[zone]==undefined) { zones[zone]=1; }
              //else { zones[zone]++; }
        });
      });
```

does not cause "so lazy" to be printed even once, even though that command output indeed outputs multiple lines--one for each utilized zone. ?? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the err?  Also there is a module that makes working with amazon AWS api much easier than what you're trying to do.  https://github.com/awssum/awssum/

Comment: Hi, there doesn't seem to be anything in err. It doesn't loop even once which is weird. Could the lines be delimited by something nonstandard? Perhaps it's worth noting that the exact same command output works fine in a perl foreach loop, but nodejs just doesn't like it?

Comment: No, otherwise you'd be getting an error.  Try JSON.stingify(zoneoue, 0, 4) and see if the object you're getting back contains significant amounts of JSON.  You can also scan through for the results you're looking for to make sure they're there.

Comment: Not sure how lazy works but typically exec will be passing a string (zoneout) to the callback and forEach will usually want an object. `JSON.parse(zoneout)`?

Comment: They are there, if I just do console.log(zoneout); it returns (each on a newline, which is eaten by the comment field): us-east-1a
us-east-1a
us-east-1c
us-east-1d
us-east-1c
us-east-1a
us-east-1a
us-east-1a

Comment: This is also then your problem.  zoneout is a string, otherwise console.log(zoneout) would print: [object object].  Use JSON.parse as Morgan suggests.  In general, if Node prints out something sensible from console.log, you're not dealing with a JSON object, and can't do things like forEach on it.

Comment: Oh, except json.parse bails on the list: http://pastebin.com/8mQ12trZ -- I got that just by calling JSON.parse(zoneout) as a parameter to lazy.

Comment: Use awssum, it goes through the process of formatig each type of response into JSON for you.  It's much easier to do than what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Listing all your instances with awssum:

```
var fmt = require('fmt');
var amazonEc2 = require('awssum-amazon-ec2');

var ec2 = new amazonEc2.Ec2({
    'accessKeyId'     : process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'secretAccessKey' : process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    'region'          : amazonEc2.US_EAST_1,
});

ec2.DescribeInstances(function(err, data) {
    fmt.dump(err, 'err');
    fmt.dump(data, 'data');
});
```

From: https://github.com/awssum/awssum-amazon-ec2/